# How to convert video to ogv and webm versions with a high quality result?

Tags: adobe

What is the best software for mac to convert video to ogv and webm versions with a high quality result?

I have adobe media encoder, is there is a setting or plugin available to do so in there? or another software that lets me control the quality of the final video to get the best quality possible. Many of the conversion programs I have tried are not providing a good quality output. The video is mp4 or mov H.264 1920 x 1080 and over 10 mins in length. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I have Premiere/Media Encoder plugins for [WebM](https://github.com/fnordware/AdobeWebM) and [Theora (OGV)](https://github.com/fnordware/AdobeOgg) on GitHub. Check the ReadMe for download links. They're currently in beta.

Brendan

Comment: I stand corrected.  Thanks for the great info and for your effort on the project.  Also, thanks for following the self-promotion rules.

Comment: Great to see you here on our Stack Exchange! I use and love a lot of your plugins. Looking forward to this one.

Comment: Hi Brendan, I downloaded the AdobeOgg plugin and ran into a roadblock during installation. The `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/` exists but the `Plug-ins/CSX/MediaCore` path doesn't. Should I create these folders? Btw, I use Premiere Pro CC on OS X Yosemite (v10.10.4).

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with command line tools, [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is top notch.

Answer (score 0):

Miro is a good (easy to use) free one
http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/